# SwiftUI scale effect from RoundedRectangle to Circle

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to make a rectangular button that on tap gesture became a circular button with a scale and smooth animation.

```
ZStack {
   ZStack {
       RegularPolygon(sides: started ? 50 : 4)
           .scale(started ? 0.75 : 1.0)
           .fill(started ? Color(.green) : .red)
   }
   .frame(width: 350, height: 200)
   .padding()
   Text(started ? "start" : "Stop")
       .font(.system(size: 36, design:.rounded))
       .fontWeight(.heavy)
}
.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5))
```

This is my code so fare but I don't like this approach and I think it's overwhelming a simple task.

What is the best approach to transform a rectangular button to a circle one with a smooth scale animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to change rectangular button to round button.

```
ZStack {
        // Rectangle CGFloat(self.isTapped ? 25.0 : 50)
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CGFloat(self.isTapped ? 25.0 : 50))
            .foregroundColor(self.isTapped ?.red :.blue)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(self.isTapped ? 200 : 100), height: CGFloat(self.isTapped ? 40 : 100), alignment: .center)
        
       Text(self.isTapped ? "Start" : "Stop")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5))
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation {
            self.isTapped.toggle()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!